# Rails:active record modeling one to many(deep nested) through different paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this complex data model, which I want to represent using Active record model objects.

`USER(user_id)` can post. Which is represented by `USER_POST(post_id,  user_id(fk))`
Other users can respond to post. Which I am encapsulating in a `CONVERSATION(conversation_id, post_id(fk), responded_by_user_id(fk))`.
All the messages exchanged between original posted and the responder (as part of the conversation) goes in `MESSAGES(message_id, conversation_id, message_text)`.

My concern comes from the fact that orinal poster navigates to messages through

`user->user_posts->conversation->messages`

where as the responder navigates to messages through

`user->conversation->messages`

There are multiple path from user to messages.

I am trying to represent in my active record model objects. The following is what I could come up with.

```
User{ 
 has_many :user_posts 
 has_many :conversations #for the case where is not through user_posts
}


UserPost{
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :conversations
}

Conversation{
 belongs_to :user #responded_by_user
 belongs_to :user_post #this links to original posted user
 has_many :messages
}

Message{
 belongs_to :conversation
}
```

Could you please let me know if you see any issues with this approach? I would also appreciate it if you can suggest any alternative approach for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though what you really have are `User`, `Post` (not sure why it was originally `UserPost`), `Conversation`, and `Message` where:

```
class User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :conversations
  has_many :messages, through: :conversations

  // If you want a user's conversations where they made the original post
  def conversations_as_poster
    self.conversations.joins(:posts).where("post.user_id = ?", self.id)
  end
end
```

```
class Post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :conversations
end
```

```
class Conversation
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :messages
end
```

```
class Message
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Please bear in mind that this isn't tested, and is only meant for reference.